# Which parameters must be saved by a Kernel Density Estimation to reload it later?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I trained a kde with sklearn and now I want to save the parameters. Which parameters are needed to fully describe a kde?
I don't want to save the kde as such, only the parameters.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's wrong with just saving all the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

### You have to train your KDE on your dataset again.

There is, as far as I know, no way to save a trained sklearn KDE model without saving the corresponding training dataset. Looking at the documentation of the `fit()` method for sklearn KernelDensity, you can see that "fitting" the model only assigns the training dataset to the KDE instance. Documentation and source code here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.fit

For reproducibility, the **hyperparameters** you may want to save are the type of kernel, the bandwidth or the distance metric to use. That said, the `fit()` method will still require the whole training dataset to sample new instances or compute the log-likelihood of a given sample.